# How should I be storing these values?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop, adt

I'm asking this as I'm questioning the best way to code my app. I have data that I'm not sure how to organise - exercises. Each exercise has a name, muscle group, instruction and image number.

These exercises are static, they do not change. I've considered creating an exercise class, but is that overkill? Could these easily be stored and manipulated in another way? I'm really unsure how to approach this, and I know partly this is my understanding, but I don't need these exercises to do anything in the app other than be displayed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You'll have to be a little bit more specific, a practical example in your question would help.

Comment: Not sure how I can give a practical example? Other than, for example, here is an exercise: Shoulder press, muscle = shoulders, instructions = set to comfortable weight, press to the top and gently bring down, image number = 0..

Answer (score 0):

If the data is truly static and you don't really have a lot of it, just store it in an Array inside of your Application class:

```
public static final Exercise[] EXERCISES = {
  new Exercise("Shoulder Press", "shoulders", "set to comfortable weight, press to the top and gently bring down", 0),
  new Exercise("Shoulder Press", "shoulders", "set to comfortable weight, press to the top and gently bring down", 0)
};

public class Exercise {
  String name;
  String muscleWorked;
  int imageNumber;

 ...
}
```